# Function that recieves an integer and returns a tuple with all of its' digits in order in Python

Tags: python

```
def function(n):
    res = 0
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise ValueError('argument is not an integer')
    else:
        while n > 0: #inverting the integer's digits
            dig = n % 10
            res = 10*res + dig
            n = n//10
    dig2 = res % 10
    res2 = (dig2,)
    res = res // 10

    while res > 0:
        dig2 = res % 10
        res2 = (res2,) + (dig2,)
        res = res // 10

return res2
```

Input: `123`
Output: `(1, 2, 3)`

With the current program that I have my output is (((1,), 2), 3).Im having trouble with creating a tuple and adding it to another tuple and also with the logic part of analyzing each digit. I'm new to python, if you could try to explain it to me wihtout the use of lists I'd also be very grateful.

Comment: It's just `res2 = res2 + (dig2,)`, as `res2` is already a tuple

Comment: Yes, it was exaclty that! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Did you mean: ‘return tuple([int(i) for i in str(n)])’?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on efficiency/performance, but take a look at the following code:

```
num = 123456789
lis = [int(char) for char in str(num)]
tup = tuple(lis)
print(tup)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Here we are using list comprehensions (which are loved by Python programmers). First, num is converted to string, then each char of this string is converted to an int, building a list of integers. The list can then be converted to a tuple.

I know you said "if you could try to explain it to me wihtout the use of lists...", but understand that lists (and list comprehensions) are an important part/tool of Python, you should not avoid them.

Again, the list comprehension above can be "read" as such:

Convert to int each char in the string (where this string is the number converted to a string).

Comment: if you are converting to a string and then to a tuple, why do you need a list?

Comment: You don't. One can use a generator like so: `tuple(int(char) for char in str(number))`. However, I believe using a list is easier to understand and more widely used.

Comment: This was also very insightful thank you so much!! :)